# Translation from .mo file not working in theme

Tags: translation, localization

I'm trying to add translations to my theme. I went through the [documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/functionality/internationalization/) and many questions here on Wordpress Development Stack.

Setted a text domain in my `style.css` file:

```
/*
Theme Name: My Theme
Text Domain: my-theme
*/
```

Loaded the text domain in my `functions.php` file:

```
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'my_theme_load_theme_textdomain' );
function my_theme_load_theme_textdomain() {
    load_theme_textdomain( 'my-theme' );
}
```

Also tried passing a 2nd argument to `load_theme_textdomain()`:

```
load_theme_textdomain( 'my-theme', get_template_directory() . '/languages' );
```

Added `_e( 'Featured', 'my-theme' )` in my `index.php` file. Also tried without the 2nd argument `_e( 'Featured' )`.

Added both `es.mo` and `es.po` files into a `languages` folder in my theme root directory.

- `languages\es.mo`
- `languages\es.po`

Also tried naming them with the text domain as a prefix: `my-theme-es.mo` and `my-theme-es.mo`.

The content of `es.po` is as follow:

```
msgid "Featured"
msgstr "Destacados"
```

The `es.mo` file was generated using [Poedit](https://poedit.net/) free version. Also tried with [po2mo.net](https://po2mo.net/).

I setted the language to spanish in the General Settings page. Also tried adding `define( 'WPLANG', 'es' )` to my `wp-config.php` file.

But *everytime* I get "Featured" instead of "Destacados" when the page is rendered.

I'm using WordPress 5.3 on Windows (XAMPP). I checked with `phpinfo()` that GetText support is enabled.

Any clues?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: you write `_e( 'Featured', ' my-theme' )` with a space before "my-theme", is it a typo ?

Comment: Good catch. Yes, it's a typo in the example. The actual code is `echo __('Featured', 'gurim')`, which uses the real name of the theme.

Comment: in the General Settings, spanish code is `es_ES`. try with filenames `es_ES.po` and `es_ES.mo`

Comment: @Kaperto You are right, it's `es_ES` but just tried that and same result. Also removed `define( 'WPLANG', 'es' )` from the config file.

Comment: look that you don't have a file `wp-content/languages/themes/my-theme-es_ES.mo`.

Comment: Copied `es_ES.mo` to `wp-content/languages/themes/my-theme-es_ES.mo` but same result.

Comment: My bad. Copying the file to `wp-content/languages/themes/my-theme-es_ES.mo` actually worked!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start a new theme from scratch to see if you have the same result. I test with theses files and the translation works

**style.css**

```
/*
Theme Name: My Theme
*/
```

**functions.php**

```
<?php

add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'my_theme_load_theme_textdomain' );

function my_theme_load_theme_textdomain() {

    load_theme_textdomain( 'my-theme', get_template_directory() . '/languages' );

}
```

**languages/es_ES.po** (file **languages/es_ES.mo** created with poedit)

```
msgid "Featured"
msgstr "Destacados"
```

**index.php**

```
<?php

_e( 'Featured', 'my-theme' );
```

Comment: Yes, at the end I didn't need to copy the .mo file to `wp-content/languages/themes`. Looks like I wasn't properly loading the textdomain. Thank you so much!